# Wikitude: communicate back from within HtmlDrawable to Java code using "architectsdk://" technique

Tags: javascript, java, android, wikitude

I'm working on an Android app and trying to implement the following solution:

within an HtmlDrawable I have a set of elements with onClick events.

By clicking on these elements I want to communicate back to the Java code of the app using the "architectsdk://" url technique.

But I don't see any response in my ArchitectView.ArchitectUrlListener() implementation.

Another note: when I set onClick event of the HtmlDrawable itself then I successfully notified within the Java code.

So the question: is it possible to communicate back to Java code from an HtmlDrawable or I need to create each element separatly and places onclicks on them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I've got an answer on the Wikitude's forum:](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/developer-forum/-/message_boards/message/1055924?p_p_auth=zK3RUW5S#_19_message_1055908)

In case if someone needs it:

> HtmlDrawables live in a different context, you therefore cannot use
>   architectsdk to communication with native Android/iOS urlListener. I
>   recommend using HtmlDrawables onClick listener instead.
>
> e.g. myHtmlDrawables.onClick = function() {
>   document.location="architectsdk://mydrawables?clicked=1"; return true;
>   }
>
> Best regards